# Why my regex doesn't work with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I am parsing an HTML file and would like to match everything between two sequences of characters: `Sent:` and the `<br>` tag.

I have seen several very similar questions and tried all of their methods and none have worked for me, probably because I'm a novice and am doing something very simple incorrectly.

Here's my relevant code:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path): #capture email year, month, day
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            html = f.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            a = re.findall(r'Sent:/.+?(?=<br>)/', soup.text)[0]
            #a = re.findall(r'Sent:(.*)', soup.text)[0]
            print(a)
            d = parser.parse(a)
            print("year:", d.year)
            print("month:", d.month)
            print("day:", d.day)
```

and I've also tried these for my RegEx: `a = re.findall(r'Sent:/^(.*?)<br>/', soup.text)[0]` and `a = re.findall(r'Sent:/^[^<br>]*/', soup.text)[0]`

But I keep getting the error `list index out of range`.... but even when I remove the `[0]` I get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'` on the line `d = parser.parse(a)`.... with only `[]` printed as a result of `print(a)`

Here's the relevant block of HTML:

```
<b>Sent:</b> Friday, June 14, 2013 12:07 PM<br><b>To:</b> David Leveille<br><b>Subject:</b>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not really your regex, but the fact that BeautifulSoup parse the HTML (its job after all) and *change* its content. For example, your `<br>` will be transformed to `<br/>`. Another point : soup.text erases all the tags, so your regex won't work anymore.

It will be more clear trying this script :

```
from bs4 import *
import re
from dateutil import parser

pattern = re.compile(r'Sent:(.+?)(?=<br/>)')

with open("myfile.html", 'r') as f:
        html = f.read()
        print("html: ", html)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        print("soup.text: ", soup.text)
        print("str(soup): ", str(soup))
        a = pattern.findall(str(soup))[0]
        print("pattern extraction: ", a)
```

For the second part : since your date string is not formally correct (because of the initial `<br/>`), you should add the parameter `fuzzy=True`, as its explained in the [documentation of dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html).

```
d = parser.parse(a, fuzzy=True)
print("year:", d.year)
print("month:", d.month)
print("day:", d.day)
```

Another solution would be to use a more precise regex. For example :

```
pattern = re.compile(r'Sent:</b>(.+?)(?=<br/>)')
```

Comment: Ohhh ok that makes a lot of sense. I printed it out and saw what you were talking about. The thing is now, though, that I un-commented the `d = parser.parse(a)` and `print()` statements below it and they still failed with the error `ValueError: Unknown string format` that has been plaguing me for a while now

Comment: To be fair, i don't understand what "parser.parse" means. What is "parser" ? I know a module named "dateparser", but i can't install it to try.

Comment: Well I was told to import `from dateutil import parser`....that way I use RegEx to capture everything after `Sent:` and then `parser()` recognizes and captures a date from within the stuff that was captured after `Sent:`......But what was happening with some emails, this one in particular, was that there was no `\n` character so the RegEx was messing up...so I noticed in the HTML there was a `<br>` at the end of the date information, so I posted this question....And now I find out I'm basically in the same quandary

Comment: OK, I understand. It's important to mention all the modules used. I've edited my answer. Feel free to accept or upvote it if it's correct.

Comment: Wow ok that worked perfectly! Thanks so much. I have never even heard of this `fuzzy` thing so thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

Can you please replace your regex with the one below that looks for the key terms and then anything between them and tell me what error if any you are now receiving?

```
a=re.findall(r"Sent:(.*?)<br>", soup.text)[0]
```

Comment: That only prints `[]`

Comment: Try is on regxr.com . I just did it. Worked for me. In this case the problem seems to be something other than the regex.

Comment: Well that's not good news... Any idea why it would be failing like this? This code worked perfectly on another HTML email but then I tried running it on this one and all these errors keep appearing from my attempts to capture just the Date

Comment: Try it now and if it still doesn't work you may need to use <\/br> if you are looking for </br> instead of <br> please get back to me on if this works

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It also takes into consideration if the `<br>` tag contains a slash.

```
/Sent:(.*?)<\/*br>/
```

Comment: all that printed was `[]` as well :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the usual slash escapes:

```
a = re.findall(r"Sent:(.*?)<br>", soup.text)[0]
```

That being said, you should probably check for the output (or at least use try/except) before trying to get a value from it.